# How to get a output in json object from azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have written a azure function which will return data into json string format but i want data into json object so that i can directly use that array output for next step into logic app.

azure function code -

```
        composeMessage = "{\"__metadata\": {\"id\": "+obj.id+",\"uri\": "+obj.uri+",\"dateForSystem\": "+obj.dateForSystem + ",\"timeForSystem\": "+obj.timeForSystem + "}";
        composeMessageList.Add(composeMessage);
        outputDerivedTableKey = string.Empty;
        startIndex = 0;
    }
     var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(composeMessageList);
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
```

getting output like -

```
[
  "{\"__metadata\": {\"id\": ,\"uri\": ,\"type\": },\"dateForSystem\": 2019-05-17,\"timeForSystem\": 13:15:51}",
  "{\"__metadata\": {\"id\": ,\"uri\": ,\"type\": },\"dateForSystem\": 2019-05-17,\"timeForSystem\": 13:15:51}",
  "{\"__metadata\": {\"id\": ,\"uri\": ,\"type\": },\"dateForSystem\": 2019-05-17,\"timeForSystem\": 13:15:51}",
]
```

But I can't pass this array to foreach in logic app i'm excepting output format like below from azure function -

```
[
  {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "",
      "uri": "",
      "type": ""
    },
    "dateForSystem": "2019-05-17",
    "timeForSystem": "13:15:51"
  },
   {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "",
      "uri": "",
      "type": ""
    },
    "dateForSystem": "2019-05-17",
    "timeForSystem": "13:15:51"
  },
   {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "",
      "uri": "",
      "type": ""
    },
    "dateForSystem": "2019-05-17",
    "timeForSystem": "13:15:51"
  },
]
```

> How can i achieve this format output from azure function ?
>
> Or how to format this into logic app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the serialized object is a list of string so Json.Net serializes it as an array of string.

Here is a simple function that use dynamic objects but you can also create a class for your `composeMessage` object:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
    ILogger log)
{
    var composeMessageList = new List<object>();
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var composeMessage = new
        {
            __metadata = new
            {
                id = "",
                uri = "",
                type = ""
            },
            dateForSystem = "2019-05-17",
            timeForSystem = "13:15:51"
        };

        composeMessageList.Add(composeMessage);
    }

    var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(composeMessageList);
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
}
```